# Scrape data from multiple webpages using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to extract the phone titles (and eventually other data) from multiple web pages using scrapy. I am trying to do this with defined functions. the "parse" function is supposed to pull all of the page links, which it does do correctly if I let it yield its results to a CSV. However when I try to set up a second "parse_pages" it seems that the code won't even try to process and i cannot get a CSV output of just the titles for each page

note: i recognize the indenting is wrong below for the functions,

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request

url = 'https://www.gsmarena.com/'

class PhonelinksSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'phonelinks'
    allowed_domains = ['www.gsmarena.com/results.php3?']
    start_urls = ['https://www.gsmarena.com/results.php3?']

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath('//div[@class="makers"]/ul/li/a/@href').extract()
        for link in links:
            location = url+link
            yield response.follow(url = location,callback = self.parse_pages)



    def parse_pages(self, response):
       phones = response.xpath('//h1[contains(@class,"specs-phone-name-title")]/text()').extract_first().strip()
       for title in phones:
           phone_list = {'phone':title}
           yield phone_list
```

Comment: Where do you call these functions? Please see: [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
phones = response.xpath('//h1[contains(@class,"specs-phone-name-title")]/text()').extract_first().strip()
```

`extract_first()` returns a `string` or `None` that's why you can iterate it on next line.

```
def parse_pages(self, response):
   title = response.xpath('//h1[contains(@class,"specs-phone-name-title")]/text()').extract_first().strip()
   yield {'phone':title}
```